# How Shadow DOM restricts us to apply styling in CSS file in LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I read number of articles but practically I am not able to understand how does shadow DOM affects the styling of nested tags. Looks like there are some styling which I could modify from css file but other few styling I am not able to modify from css file. I am not sure how Shadom DOM is restricting us to do so. Can anyone please help me to understand what is shadow DOM and which styling we can modify in css file and what kind of styling we can't modify, with the help of examples? Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shadow DOM makes the component into a "black box", meaning you can style the entire component, but you can't apply styles to things inside the component. So, given:

```
<template>
  <!-- c-my-component -->
  <div></div>
</template>
```

You can style the outer template (e.g. add a border, change dimensions, etc), but you can't style the div within the template from outside. In other words, given:

```
<template>
  <c-my-component></c-my-component>
</template>
```

You can't "see" the div in this component, so you can't style that div, either. That's pretty much the core idea. Whatever you can see in a component's source directly, you can style, and anything you can't see, you can't.

Comment: Okay, it make sense now. But there are some use cases in which I applied styling to some standard CSS classes which I got from inspect element and the styling was rendering pretty well. But when I applied styling to some other standard CSS class in the same CSS file the style is not rendering. Does it mean, that the class was in the shadow root that's why I was able to style it? and the other class is not in Shadow root that's why I couldn't style it? If yes, then how would I know which tag falls in shadow root and which doesn't when I open inspect element to apply styling?

Comment: This happens when I am applying styling within the same component itself. How can we determine the shadow DOM from inspect element?

Comment: @sfdc07 In most browsers, it should show something like #shadowRoot up the hierarchy to let you know where the boundaries are. But the easiest way is to look at the source code. Do you see the element you're attempting to style in the source code? If not, you can't style it at all.

Comment: Okay, yea the element is not in the source code. So what I usually do is , for e.g. Let's say in case of lightning - datatable, if at all I need to style the datatable, I inspect element it, find the appropriate class to which I could apply that styling to and use that class in css file or if that appropriate class is nested in another element then in that case it causes issues.

Comment: @sfdc07 Correct. Elements are to be treated as single units that cannot be directly accessed from outside, what programmers call a "black box." Stuff goes in, other stuff comes out, but the contents are unimportant (and inaccessible). If you need enhanced data table behavior, you may want to look at the docs for creating custom cells, or write your own component.